# Selenium-based scraping code fails with the error NoSuchElementException

Tags: python, html, selenium

I have a Python code that scraps different data. For example, it scraps the `Website` from this [HTML code](https://topicolist.com/ico/adhive):

```
<a data-ix="show-popup-on-click" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="https://mylink.org/" class="button full w-button" style="transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;">Website</a>
```

It was working properly, but now it fails with the error:

> NoSuchElementException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Unable to find
>   element with link text
>   'Website'","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"95","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:40581","User-Agent":"Python
>   http auth"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\":
>   \"link text\", \"sessionId\":
>   \"a7a441f0-0f6a-11e8-ad3a-6121f74a30f4\", \"value\":
>   \"Website\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/a7a441f0-0f6a-11e8-ad3a-6121f74a30f4/element"}}
>   Screenshot: available via screen

This is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)
driver.get(link)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

website = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Website").get_attribute("href")
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

```
<div class="column-space w-col w-col-4">
   <a data-ix="show-popup-on-click" target="_blank" 
      rel="nofollow" href="https://example.com/" 
      class="button full w-button" 
      style="transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;">Website</a>

   <div class="space big"></div>
   <a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" 
      href="https://example.com/storage/b/2/0/2/WhitepaperLive.pdf" 
      class="button-2 w-button">Whitepaper</a>
   <div class="space big"></div>
   <a class="button-2 w-condition-invisible w-button">Program</a>
   <div class="space big w-condition-invisible"></div>
   <div>
      <div class="div-block-4 w-clearfix">
         <div class="div-block-2">Token:</div>
         <div class="div-block-5 w-clearfix">
            <div class="text-block-12">UTC</div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="div-block-4 w-clearfix">
         <div class="div-block-2">Price:</div>
         <div class="div-block-5 w-clearfix">
            <div class="text-block-12">1 LUC=0,05 USD</div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="div-block-4 w-clearfix">
         <div class="div-block-2">Buy with:</div>
         <div class="div-block-5 w-clearfix">
            <div class="text-block-12">USD, EUR</div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="div-block-4 w-clearfix">
         <div class="div-block-2">Platform:</div>
         <div class="div-block-5 w-clearfix">
            <div class="text-block-12">MyPlatform</div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="div-block-4 w-clearfix w-condition-invisible">
         <div class="div-block-2">KYC:</div>
         <div class="div-block-5 w-clearfix">
            <div class="text-block-12">No</div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="div-block-4 w-clearfix">
         <div class="div-block-2">KYC:</div>
         <div class="div-block-5 w-clearfix">
            <div class="text-block-12">Yes</div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="div-block-4 w-clearfix">
         <div class="div-block-2">Location:</div>
         <div class="div-block-5 w-clearfix">
            <div class="text-block-12">Malta</div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="div-block-4 w-clearfix">
         <div class="div-block-2">Can't join:</div>
         <div class="div-block-5 w-clearfix">
            <div class="text-block-12">USA</div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="space big"></div>
      <div class="div-block-4 w-clearfix">
         <div class="div-block-2">Start:</div>
         <div class="div-block-5 w-clearfix">
            <div class="text-block-12">January 25, 2018</div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="div-block-4 w-clearfix">
         <div class="div-block-2">End:</div>
         <div class="div-block-5 w-clearfix">
            <div class="text-block-12">February 5, 2018</div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="space big"></div>
      <div class="div-block-4 w-clearfix">
         <div class="div-block-2">Start2:</div>
         <div class="div-block-5 w-clearfix">
            <div class="text-block-12">February 12, 2018</div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="div-block-4 w-clearfix">
         <div class="div-block-2">End2:</div>
         <div class="div-block-5 w-clearfix">
            <div class="text-block-12">March 5, 2018</div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div>
         <div class="div-block-33">
            <div class="space big"></div>
            <div>
               <a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" 
               class="button green full w-condition-invisible w-button">JOIN WHITELIST NOW »</a>
               <div class="div-block-34">
                  <a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="http://we-do-not-have-slack.com" 
                     class="link-block-2 w-inline-block">
                     <img src="https://global-uploads.webflow.com/903_slack-symbol.png" alt="ICO Slack link">
                  </a>
                  <a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="https://twitter.com/live" class="link-block-2 w-inline-block">
                     <img src="https://global-uploads.webflow.com/f4000142b091_twitter%20(1).png" width="16" alt="ICO Twitter link">
                  </a>
                  <a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="https://t.me/live" class="link-block-2 w-inline-block">
                     <img src="https://global-uploads.webflow.com/790001798dfe_telegram.png" alt="ICO Telegram link">
                  </a>
                  <a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="http://we-do-not-have-GitHub.com" class="link-block-2 w-inline-block">
                     <img src="https://global-uploads.webflow.com/59cf77c1fb0edc0001b4b26a_github-logo.png" alt="ICO GitHun link">
                  </a>
                  <a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.facebook.com/Play2Live-504880049864038/" class="link-block-2 w-inline-block">
                     <img src="https://global-uploads.webflow.com/59cf77c1fb0edc0001b4b117/59d510290116ac0001964c8e_facebook.png" alt="Facebook link">
                  </a>
                  <a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="https://talk.org/index.php?topic=2381679.0" class="link-block-2 w-inline-block">
                     <img src="https://global-uploads.webflow.com/0011f8c3c_talk.jpg" alt="Talk link">
                  </a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share more of the HTML? And possibly even the `text` of a parent element that you *can* successfully `find_*`?

Comment: @Ian: yes, other `find_*` work well.

Comment: @Ian: I uploaded whole HTML code.

Comment: What is the nearest ancestor element that you can successfully find with Selenium? And what is that element's `text` value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException" when using Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome)

Comment: try giving some sleep

Comment: @I gave sleep `time.sleep(10)`. I can extract, for example, UTC.

Comment: @Markus , I found out the issue and posted the answer , please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem in the code , on inspecting the `Website`link from web page  i can see the text as "Website" but if i use the same text to find the element by link text like below i am getting `NoSuchElementException`

```
website = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Website").get_attribute("href")
print(website)
```

I have tried giving 'waits' and used `partial_link_text` also but no luck.

Then i tried fetching all the element of tag name "a" and print the text from those with the below code.

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
for element in elements:
    print(element.text)
```

Later i got to know its not the "Website" its "WEBSITE". But i am not sure why its behaving like this.

After changing the all characters od website to capital i am able to identify the element and fetch the `href` from that.

```
driver.get("https://topicolist.com/ico/adhive")
website = driver.find_element_by_link_text("WEBSITE").get_attribute("href")
print(website)
```

Hope its solves your problem.

Comment: I am curious why it's WEBSITE? How did you find it out?

Comment: i just captured all web element with tag name a and printed the text

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when Selenium can't find the object in the HTML DOM.

My guess is that you set up your implicit wait too late, and Selenium tries to get the Element before the page is loaded and the element present in the HTML DOM.

```
driver.get(link)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

The documentation sets up the implicit wait before getting any pages:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get(link)
```

This ensures that selenium waits until the page is fully loaded before it looks for the anchor tag element.

DocLink: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#implicit-waits

Also if there are no elements on that page you are scraping that are loaded or created via javascript, then you don't need selenium to do simple text extraction scraping. You could just use the core library urllib.request to get the page and then scrape with beautifulSoup.

**UPDATE:**

As Ian in said in the comments, implicit wait positioning doesn't matter in this case.

The Problem was the Locator Strategy.

```
website = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Website').get_attribute('href')
```

In this case it couldn't find the element, which is a Link styled to a button with uppercase lettering WEBSITE.
It seems to match not the link text in the HTML DOM ("Website") but the css computed style rendered text WEBSITE on the button.

Another locator strategy like css-selector or XPATH seems to me to deliver more reliable results:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Website')]").get_attribute("href")
```

Some more information on those can be found here:
[Selenium Locating Elements](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html?highlight=locating)

Comment: It doesn't matter when `implicitly_wait()` is called so long as it happens before the `find_*` that must wait.

Comment: Like Ian said, my guess is wrong as the implicit wait statement positioning doesn't matter in this case. It looks like we need more information to help.

Comment: I am extracting "Website" from this link https://topicolist.com/ico/adhive. Could you please check it?

Comment: Okay, thanks for posting the link. I did some tests and got it working. It looks like it's because of your Locator Strategy. `driver.find_element_by_link_text("WEBSITE")` seems to work, where "Website" doesnt. It looks like find_element_by_link_text doesn't use the Text in the HTML DOM to match, but the computed style rendered text.